# How to plot a graph from center mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to make starting point of the plot (0 this time) to be plotted from center of the view. I can manage this by setting spaceMin to the half of the grid range. but when zooming, i need to change that value 'cause range changes. but calling setSpaceMin in the onChartGestureListener does nothing. here what I want to get by [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOeTG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `setDragOffsetX()` with half-width of your viewport